# PHP redirection to multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql

I have login page that has four options after logging in; you either go to your account services, your dashboard, your payments or loan services. 
Which code can I use to make sure that if a customer selected any of these in the dropdown, it would redirect him to the right page?

Comment: Use `header`. Check manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<select>` to your login form.

```
<select name="page">
    <option value="accounts">Accounts</option>
    <option value="dashboard">Dashboard</option>
    <option value="payment">Payment</option>
    <option value="loan">Loan</option>
</select>
```

After User has been validated add following line of code to redirect to specific page.

```
switch($_POST['page']){
    case "accounts":
        header("Location: accounts.php");
        break;
    case "dashboard":
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        break;
    case "payment":
        header("Location: payment.php");
        break;
    case "loan":
        header("Location: loan.php");
        break;
    # By Default Redirect to Dashboard.
    default:
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        break;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Shrunken code : Write this after user is validated.

```
header("Location: ".$_POST['page'].".php");
```

Comment: This is called WET programming.. I advice you to look at [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['selected_value'])
{
  switch ($_POST['selected_value']) {
   case "account_services":
      header("location:account_services.php");
      break;
   case "dashboard":
      header("location:dashboard.php");
    break;
      echo "Error message";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ew, use a `switch`, please...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you give difference of `switch` and `IF..ELSE`?

Comment: how many if else can I use? coz i have 4 options

Comment: @Sadikhasan `switch` is much more readable, easier to add cases to, and if you decide to change the `$_POST` variable's name then you only have to change it once. Among other reasons.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for suggession I change according to it